# Use Case statement in Join resulting in error

Tags: sql, oracle19c

I am trying to use a CASE statement inside a Join below. Essentially if the `cce.LOCATOR_ID is NULL` then I just want to say 1=1 (to evaluate true), otherwise (if cce.LOCATOR_ID is **NOT** Null) then I want to join `DEF.LOCATOR_ID = cce.LOCATOR_ID`. This is erroring with `ORA-00905: missing keyword`

```
SELECT cce.ITEM_NUMBER, DEF.SEGMENT1
FROM INV_CYCLE_COUNT_ENTRIES cce
LEFT OUTER JOIN inv_item_loc_defaults DEF ON FEF.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = cce.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID   
   AND DEF.SUBINVENTORY_CODE = cce.SUBINVENTORY
   AND DEF.DEFAULT_TYPE = 2
   AND CASE WHEN cce.LOCATOR_ID IS NULL THEN 1=1 ELSE DEF.LOCATOR_ID = cce.LOCATOR_ID END
```

It seems as if the last line needs to be changed to something like: `AND cce.LOCATOR_ID = CASE WHEN cce.LOCATOR_ID IS NULL THEN ????` I don't know what to put here when the CASE statement is after the equal sign and just have it evaluate to true, like with 1=1 above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use AND/OR logic

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN inv_item_loc_defaults DEF ON FEF.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = cce.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID   
   AND DEF.SUBINVENTORY_CODE = cce.SUBINVENTORY
   AND DEF.DEFAULT_TYPE = 2
   AND (cce.LOCATOR_ID IS NULL or DEF.LOCATOR_ID = cce.LOCATOR_ID)
```

Comment: that will be logically equivalent to the CASE statement I proposed?

Comment: Yes; have you tested it?

Answer (score 1):

Use simple `OR`:

```sql
SELECT cce.ITEM_NUMBER, DEF.SEGMENT1
FROM INV_CYCLE_COUNT_ENTRIES cce
LEFT OUTER JOIN inv_item_loc_defaults DEF ON FEF.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = cce.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID   
   AND DEF.SUBINVENTORY_CODE = cce.SUBINVENTORY
   AND DEF.DEFAULT_TYPE = 2
   AND (cce.LOCATOR_ID IS NULL OR DEF.LOCATOR_ID = cce.LOCATOR_ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can write your query without using case like below
As you want to Join only when Locater_ID is not null

```
SELECT cce.ITEM_NUMBER, DEF.SEGMENT1
FROM INV_CYCLE_COUNT_ENTRIES cce
LEFT OUTER JOIN inv_item_loc_defaults DEF ON FEF.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = 
cce.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID   
AND DEF.SUBINVENTORY_CODE = cce.SUBINVENTORY
AND DEF.DEFAULT_TYPE = 2
AND cce.LOCATOR_ID IS NOT NULL 
AND DEF.LOCATOR_ID = cce.LOCATOR_ID
```

Moreover, CASE statement syntax in where clause is like -

```
SELECT col1,col2, col3
FROM table1 
WHERE col2 = CASE col1
WHEN condition 1 THEN result1
ELSE result2
END
```

Comment: Your join condition is not correct as it does not match when `cce.LOCATOR_ID IS NULL`.